# Generate heatmap using canvas in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, heatmap

I want to know how can I generate a heatmap on a canvas in WPF (.NET)

I have an array of points (coordinates) with the color intensity, with these data I want to create something similar to this

[image]

But, I found that there is no tutorial or library to generate them on a canvas..

Answer (score 1):

I am very sorry, but you have it wrong. WPF canvas is a sandbox for higher level objects, not points. So there are rectangles, circles, ellipses, lines, polylines etc, but more you put in, slower it gets. Now an image like an heat map could use tens of thousands points or even millions of points and that would be a pretty bad idea to play with it directly in canvas. For this kind manipulation, you need pixels to play with and it means special kind of container, like [WritableImage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx). Please look on the link.

This kind container/class is capable manipulate efficiently with pixels, and that is the way it should be done.

Please note, that there are multiple kinds of bitmap containers for WPF.

Comment: thanks for the info, but how to generate the heatmap?

Comment: @Tim Create a WriteableBitmap of appropriate size, then set its pixels to appropriate colors values. Read the documentation.

Comment: @Clemens ty for ur reply, i understand how to create that bitmap and the canvas rendering, i want to know how to create that colour contour

Comment: @Tim That is a different question, not at all related to WPf or C#. Search the web for heatmap or contour plot algorithms.